# filter by string date field in couchDb or mongoDb

Tags: regex, mongodb, nosql, couchdb

I have date stored in string format in `couchDb` and selector I want in which I want to filter data for last 2 days.

string date field is in format of `"2021-12-17T18:18:49.605Z"`

I want to add selector in such a way that it will extract data for last 48 hours, even if it filters for last 2 date, it will be great for me.

It can be done by regex either but I am not sure. Following works but for single date.

```
{
   "selector": {
      "dateCreatedInBC": {
         "$regex": "^2022-01-05"
      }
   }
}
```

I want regex for date `2022-01-05` or `2022-01-06`

Comment: Beware that `regex` for CouchDB does not work with indexes and will trigger a full table scan. See the last part of [1.3.6.1.8. Condition Operators](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/find.html?highlight=regex#selector-basics).  If the db is very large this may well be, or become, an issue.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB or CouchDB?

I am not familiar with CouchDB, assuming the syntax is correct, your query should be OK

In case of MongoDB my first response is: Date/Time values should be **never** stored as string, it's a design flaw. Store always proper `Date` objects.

Then it could be this one:

```
db.collection.find({ dateCreatedInBC: {$gt: new Date() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 2} })
```